# JAVA + SQLITE CÓMO HACER BUILD A UN .JAR *PROBLEMA*

Tags: java, java-swing, sqlite

Os explico.

He querido hacer una aplicación en java Swing con Sqlite porque quería que fuera portable. La aplicación es una chuminada, una aplicación para guardar películas y las vuelca en una tabla.

Una vez terminé la aplicación le hice build y la carpeta en donde estaba el .jar me la pasé a otro ordenador para probarlo.

La cosa es que en otro ordenador me da error al iniciar el .jar. (Se supone que es por algo del sqlite ya que el error de "null pointer excention" se corresponde a cuando no encuentra la base de datos. No sé qué hacer.

[image: 1]

Comment: Agrega tu código como texto por favor

Comment: Del código no hay que agregar mucho, lo importante lo he añadido en la foto, que es la conexión a la base de datos sqlite. La pregunta iba si hacía falta algo para que la aplicación funcionase en otro pc